# Set Session in PHP email doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, email, session

Lol, it seems that this question has not ever been asked before in google.

So, what I am trying to do is to send email via php form. The scenario of this is the registered member will invite thier friend to our page by typing as many as email address to the text area. When they submit the form, the form will send email to the all email address they enters in the text area.

This email actually is a news letter. Where in the email there would be some products to show to the addressed email.

What I want to do with the $_SESSION in the email is: when the people who has the email adress click one of products in the news letter and come to  the page, the page will get from whom he got the link to the page.

**[EDIT]**

I dont want to achieve it with a string like this: `index.php?email=$email&username=$username` since this can only be set to one link not global link and **this can also be manipulated by the new coming people.**

What I mean by global link is, as what I mentioned above, there would be many products I am going to represent in the newsletter, such as ../product-a.php, ../product-b.php, ../product-c.php, ../product-d.php, and so on. And it will make us to create many different sessions in all pages because all user who have clicked one of the product will explore the website first before deciding to buy the product or register to the website.

So, here is my code to set the session:

```
      <?php

      $kemail=$_POST['to'];
      $to  = "$kemail";

      $referal_identity = "dsfsdf";
      $referal_address = "sadasdad@sada.com";
      $_SESSION['referal_identity']=$referal_identity;
      $_SESSION['referal_address']=$referal_address;



      $subject = 'Your Friend is good';
      // message
      $message = '<html>
                  <head>
                  <title>From our company</title>
                  </head>
                    <body>
                      <p>Your friend invite you. Click this <a href="index"> link </a> </p>
                    </body>
                  </html>';
      $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'From: Klaudia <klaudia@srsrsrthisesr.com>' . "\r\n";
      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

      ?>


        <form action="" method="post">
          Email: <textarea name="to"></textarea>
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
        </form>
```

### Some test in index.page

```
                <?php
                session_start();        

                    $referal_identity=$_SESSION['referal_identity'];
                    $referal_address=$_SESSION['referal_address'];

                ?>

                        <body>


                        <?php echo $referal_identity ?>
                        <?php echo $referal_address ?>


                        <p><a href="test-referal.php">test-referal.php</a></p>

                        </body>
```

---

---

---

If we just created a session in the email, then we can call it in one time in all page for all links of webpage. That's why I want to do it with SESSION, or something like that.

---

Comment: Where do you include the referral information in the link being clicked in the email?  Sessions don't extend beyond the user currently using the website.  The users coming from clicking the link in the email will need to have some way to identify where they came from, and the standard approach for that is to include in the link some query string value representing a referral.

Comment: as far my understanding of the question, it doesn't work the way you want. you need have some sort of identification in the link. like `e.g. token=blahblah` against which, you can check from the mailing list.

Comment: session is dependent on each users and it cannot be common among multiple users

Comment: you forgot to add session_start() in the first code block.

Comment: @itachi, if i use token, then it only be able to direct the user to one link of the token.

Comment: @klaudia: Regarding your edit... Consider this from a purely logical view regardless of sessions or links or any technical concerns. When a user is viewing this email, what do you know of that user? What information can you control? The answer is simple... *none*. Your website has no control over or visibility into anybody's email. The *only* information you have is the information that user brings when clicking on a link. And the *only* way to put information on a link is in a URL parameter. No matter how many times you say that you want to do something impossible, it's still impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are used to track a particular user visiting the website for a relatively small frame of time.  They don't do what you're trying to do.

Take a look at the link in the email:

```
Click this <a href="index"> link </a>
```

That link is *all you have* for transferring data from that email body back to the website.  So that link is going to need to carry some sort of identifier.

When a user creates these referrals, generate some kind of token.  Any unique string will do.  Save that token in your database to identify the information about that referral.  This can include any information you want to track.  Then include that token in the email:

```
Click this <a href="http://somewebsite.com/index?referral=' . urlencode($someToken) . '"> link </a>
```

So the user would click on this:

```
Click this <a href="http://somewebsite.com/index?referral=abc123"> link </a>
```

Now when this user clicks on the link to visit your site, you can get that token:

```
$_GET["referral"]
```

And you can use that value to check the database for any of the data you're tracking.  This will tell you which referral brought that particular new user to the site.

You can generate multiple tokens for multiple purposes along how ever many dimensions you want to track for referrals.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It's very nice. However, if i set a token, you can see that it is only for one link. What I am trying to do with the news letter is to present our products, where each products will have their own link.

Comment: @klaudia: You can add the token to multiple links.  Variables can be re-used.  Once the user comes to the site, you can permanently track in the database the referral which originally brought them there.  Any time you generate any output for that user at any point in the future you can conditionally modify that output based on the data you've tracked for that user, just like with any data-driven web application.  There's nothing stopping you from doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you are having some misconceptions.

the session won't get carried into the email. the easiest way to serve the purpose is.... yes, a **token**.

## Steps:

- before `mail()` generate a token. (any unique random string will do)
- while generating the links e.g. `<a href="http://example.com/product1">Product 1</a>` you will add the token like this:

  `<a href="http://example.com/product1?token=$token">Product 1</a>`
- this step is also before sending the mail. you need to save that token against the email address somewhere. e.g.

  ```
   ID    email              token
   1    mail@example.com    abcdefg1
   2    mail2@example.com   abcdefg2
  ```

  - after that, send the mail
  - when someone comes to your site following this token, you can check it against the above table and can know, from which email he has come.

Comment: So, can you help me how to hide the token in the browser url but still able to get it?

Comment: you don't need to hide the token.

Comment: If i don't hide it, then it can be changed by people. And when people change it, it will send an unknown token to the database.

Comment: if an unknown token is sent to the database, then show them a 404 error page. they didn't get the desired page because they manipulated with the url which wasn't what you intended.

Comment: And that's why the only way to do this is with session.

Comment: you __can not__ do with session. it is technically impossible. (unless somehow you own all the mail servers). token way is what every site uses. when you get a verfication mail for sigining up on any website, check their link. they have a token.... it is the standard practice.